# Quantum computing questions from TP

Tags: support, site-salvage

Looks like the [quantum-computing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) questions from TP>SE made their way out here by accident (I think they were supposed to be hand-flagged and migrated which may not have worked out).

I myself don't know much about this topic, so I dunno which of them ought to be migrated. Also, we may want to consider migrating the non-TP questions in [quantum-computing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-computing) while we're at it.

Edit: Looks like there are [quantum-information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-information) questions as well. SInce there are 33-is QI questions migrated from TP, I used jQuery on the migrated questions list:

```
s="";$('pre')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  }).filter(function(){return !!this.data.match(/(quantum-computing)|(quantum-info)/ig)}).prev().each(function(){s+=this.href+"\n\n";});
```

Mods, here's the list:

[Many body quantum states analyzed as probabilistic sequences](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/many-body-quantum-states-analyzed-as-probabilistic-sequences)

[Matlab package: graphical calculus for quantum operations (esp. linear optics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/matlab-package-graphical-calculus-for-quantum-operations-esp-linear-optics)

[Spatial and polarizing beam splitters in a graphical calculus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27094/spatial-and-polarizing-beam-splitters-in-a-graphical-calculus)

[Quantum computing and quantum control](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/quantum-computing-and-quantum-control)

[Stabilizer formalism for symmetric spin-states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27272/stabilizer-formalism-for-symmetric-spin-states)

[direct sum of anyons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27080/direct-sum-of-anyons)

<s>https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27533/rigorous-security-proof-for-wiesners-quantum-money</s>  [MIGRATED]

[A resource theory of quantum discord?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27770/a-resource-theory-of-quantum-discord)

[What is the Holevo-Schumacher-Westmoreland capacity of a Pauli channel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/what-is-the-holevo-schumacher-westmoreland-capacity-of-a-pauli-channel)

[Explicit construction for unitary extensions of completely positive and trace preserving (CPTP) maps?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27657/explicit-construction-for-unitary-extensions-of-cptp-maps)

[State of Matrix Product States](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27043/state-of-matrix-product-states)

[What Shannon channel capacity bound is associated to two coupled spins?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/what-shannon-channel-capacity-bound-is-associated-to-two-coupled-spins)

[Allowed states vis-a-vis allowed dynamics in generalized probabilistic theories (GPTs)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27673/allowed-states-vis-a-vis-allowed-dynamics-in-generalized-probabilistic-theories)

<s>https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27627/master-equations-and-operator-sum-form</s>  [MIGRATED]

[Accurate quantum state estimation via "Keeping the experimentalist honest"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/accurate-quantum-state-estimation-via-keeping-the-experimentalist-honest)

[Operator norm directly from phase space representation of photonic quantum operator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/operator-norm-directly-from-phase-space-representation-of-photonic-quantum-opera)

[CHSH violation and entanglement of quantum states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27191/chsh-violation-and-entanglement-of-quantum-states)

[Depolarizing threshold for CSS codes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26983/depolarizing-threshold-for-css-codes)

[Can the concurrence be calculated in terms of the entanglement of formation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/can-the-concurrence-be-calculated-in-terms-of-the-entanglement-of-formation)

[Constructing a CP map with some decaying property](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27445/constructing-a-cp-map-with-some-decaying-property)

[Quantum memories: What are they?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27546/quantum-memories-what-are-they)

[Unknown quantum state with promise of classical data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27723/unknown-quantum-state-with-promise-of-classical-data)

[Entanglement and conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/entanglement-and-conservation)

<s>[Is the universe a quantum computer - is light speed barrier a computational constraint](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27496/is-the-universe-a-quantum-computer-is-light-speed-barrier-a-computational-cons)</s>  [MERGED]

[Monte Carlo integration over space of quantum states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27766/monte-carlo-integration-over-space-of-quantum-states)

[Functional relations for Kochen-Specker proofs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27246/functional-relations-for-kochen-specker-proofs)

[States diagonal in the tensor product of Bell states.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27789/states-diagonal-in-the-tensor-product-of-bell-states)

[Geometric picture behind quantum expanders](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/geometric-picture-behind-quantum-expanders)

[What is the physical difference between states and unital completely positive maps?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/what-is-the-physical-difference-between-states-and-unital-completely-positive-ma)

[Looking for description of Helstrom's measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/looking-for-description-of-helstroms-measurement)

[partial trace with sparse matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27781/partial-trace-with-sparse-matrices)

[What is a Hilbert space filter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26932/what-is-a-hilbert-space-filter)

[Convert state Vectors to Bloch Sphere angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/convert-state-vectors-to-bloch-sphere-angles)

[What is the use of a Universal-NOT gate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26864/what-is-the-use-of-a-universal-not-gate)

[Counting complete sets of mutually unbiased bases composed of stabilizer states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26805/counting-complete-sets-of-mutually-unbiased-bases-composed-of-stabilizer-states)

[Principle behind fidelity balance in quantum cloning](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/principle-behind-fidelity-balance-in-quantum-cloning)

[Relevance of SIC-POVMs to quantum information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/relevance-of-sic-povms-to-quantum-information)

[What proof techniques have failed for solving the SIC-POVM problem and what new insights have been gleaned from them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/what-proof-techniques-have-failed-for-solving-the-sic-povm-problem-and-what-new)

[Decoherence and measurement in NMR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/decoherence-and-measurement-in-nmr)

[Examples of number theory showing up in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26856/examples-of-number-theory-showing-up-in-physics)

Answer (score 2):

Of the questions identified, I think these ones are likely suitable for migration to TCS:

[Many body quantum states analyzed as probabilistic sequences](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/many-body-quantum-states-analyzed-as-probabilistic-sequences)

[Spatial and polarizing beam splitters in a graphical calculus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27094/spatial-and-polarizing-beam-splitters-in-a-graphical-calculus)

[Quantum computing and quantum control](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/quantum-computing-and-quantum-control)

[Stabilizer formalism for symmetric spin-states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27272/stabilizer-formalism-for-symmetric-spin-states)

[A resource theory of quantum discord?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27770/a-resource-theory-of-quantum-discord)

[What is the Holevo-Schumacher-Westmoreland capacity of a Pauli channel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/what-is-the-holevo-schumacher-westmoreland-capacity-of-a-pauli-channel)

[What Shannon channel capacity bound is associated to two coupled spins?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/what-shannon-channel-capacity-bound-is-associated-to-two-coupled-spins)

[Allowed states vis-a-vis allowed dynamics in generalized probabilistic theories (GPTs)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27673/allowed-states-vis-a-vis-allowed-dynamics-in-generalized-probabilistic-theories)

[Accurate quantum state estimation via "Keeping the experimentalist honest"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27634/accurate-quantum-state-estimation-via-keeping-the-experimentalist-honest)

[CHSH violation and entanglement of quantum states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27191/chsh-violation-and-entanglement-of-quantum-states)

[Depolarizing threshold for CSS codes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26983/depolarizing-threshold-for-css-codes)

[Can the concurrence be calculated in terms of the entanglement of formation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/can-the-concurrence-be-calculated-in-terms-of-the-entanglement-of-formation)

[Constructing a CP map with some decaying property](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27445/constructing-a-cp-map-with-some-decaying-property)

[Unknown quantum state with promise of classical data](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27723/unknown-quantum-state-with-promise-of-classical-data)

[Functional relations for Kochen-Specker proofs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27246/functional-relations-for-kochen-specker-proofs)

[States diagonal in the tensor product of Bell states.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27789/states-diagonal-in-the-tensor-product-of-bell-states)

[Geometric picture behind quantum expanders](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27738/geometric-picture-behind-quantum-expanders)

[What is a Hilbert space filter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26932/what-is-a-hilbert-space-filter)

[What is the use of a Universal-NOT gate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26864/what-is-the-use-of-a-universal-not-gate)

[Counting complete sets of mutually unbiased bases composed of stabilizer states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26805/counting-complete-sets-of-mutually-unbiased-bases-composed-of-stabilizer-states)

[Principle behind fidelity balance in quantum cloning](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26890/principle-behind-fidelity-balance-in-quantum-cloning)

[Relevance of SIC-POVMs to quantum information](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/relevance-of-sic-povms-to-quantum-information)

[What proof techniques have failed for solving the SIC-POVM problem and what new insights have been gleaned from them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/what-proof-techniques-have-failed-for-solving-the-sic-povm-problem-and-what-new)

and these ones should remain with us:

[direct sum of anyons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27080/direct-sum-of-anyons)

[Explicit construction for unitary extensions of completely positive and trace preserving (CPTP) maps?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27657/explicit-construction-for-unitary-extensions-of-cptp-maps)

[State of Matrix Product States](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27043/state-of-matrix-product-states)

[Operator norm directly from phase space representation of photonic quantum operator](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/operator-norm-directly-from-phase-space-representation-of-photonic-quantum-opera)

[Quantum memories: What are they?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27546/quantum-memories-what-are-they)

[Entanglement and conservation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27484/entanglement-and-conservation)

[What is the physical difference between states and unital completely positive maps?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27728/what-is-the-physical-difference-between-states-and-unital-completely-positive-ma)

[Looking for description of Helstrom's measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27433/looking-for-description-of-helstroms-measurement)

[Convert state Vectors to Bloch Sphere angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/convert-state-vectors-to-bloch-sphere-angles)

[Decoherence and measurement in NMR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/decoherence-and-measurement-in-nmr)

[Examples of number theory showing up in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26856/examples-of-number-theory-showing-up-in-physics)

and these are miscellaneous cases:

[Matlab package: graphical calculus for quantum operations (esp. linear optics)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/matlab-package-graphical-calculus-for-quantum-operations-esp-linear-optics)
probably off topic for us, not sure if this should go to TCS or Computational Science or neither

[partial trace with sparse matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27781/partial-trace-with-sparse-matrices)
off topic for us but appropriate for Computational Science

[Monte Carlo integration over space of quantum states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27766/monte-carlo-integration-over-space-of-quantum-states)
off topic for us but appropriate for Computational Science

Comment: Cool, you've started merging 'em. Carry on :)

Comment: It was just the one I found that needed to be merged... if you see any more that were cross-posts then please flag them, of course, but I don't think there will be much more merging to do.

Comment: Oops, meant migrate. Both start with an 'm' :/

Comment: Was summoned here from the teacher's lounge. It might be best to ask the erstwhile TP mods (Joe Fitzsimmons is one who has high rep on cstheory). I'll take a look as well over the next few days